# Why the vuforia sample won't work on Magic Leap 2?

Tags: vuforia, magic-leap

I would like to use the sample I find on the asset store at the following link for Magic Leap 2. https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/templates/packs/vuforia-magic-leap-2-sample-245664

I set up everything as required but I just won't be able to run any feature on the device. I am not sure what I am missing.

I tried to
create a new project from scratch and importing the sample from the asset store
import the package in our existing project

I have a valid Vuforia license
I have allowed every checkbox in the magic leap manifest
I scanned my space through spaces as recommended in the guide
Been able to build it but I cannot see any image popping when looking at target/vumarkers/models
Just seems like the features are not working, even with the recommended setup, am I missing something?

I tried isolate the environment and this is my setup
Vuforia 10.14.4
Unity 2022.02.0f1
"com.magicleap.unitysdk": "file:com.magicleap.unitysdk.tgz", (coming with the sample) meaning 1.3.0
"com.ptc.vuforia.engine": "file:com.ptc.vuforia.engine-10.14.4.tgz",
mlsdk v1.1.0

I tried isolate the environment and this is my setup
Vuforia 10.14.4
Unity 2022.02.0f1
"com.magicleap.unitysdk": "file:com.magicleap.unitysdk.tgz", (coming with the sample) meaning 1.3.0
"com.ptc.vuforia.engine": "file:com.ptc.vuforia.engine-10.14.4.tgz",
mlsdk v1.1.0

the features won't be running on device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be sure to use the [Getting Started with Vuforia Engine and Magic Leap 2 article](https://library.vuforia.com/getting-started/getting-started-vuforia-engine-and-magic-leap-2) as a reference for setting up your project.

Comment: Hi there I went through all of the steps and I couldn't make it work, multiple members of my team had the same issue. Could you please share a footage of the image tracking working and share every possible details of your project setup? you can reach out directly to alessio.grancini@gmail.com or agrancini@magicleap.com. Thanks

Comment: Hello. Can you confirm that you've met all the prerequisites in the article? The documentation says “Download and install the Unity Editor v. 2022.2.2f1 or newer”, but your post mentions 2022.2.0f1. There were some Unity-side fixes in 2022.2.2f1 which are crucial for ML2.

Comment: seems like upgrading the editor made it work, thank you

Comment: btw an important detail is that, when you import the template from the asset store that overwrite your project settings etc. it says that the template has been made in unity version 2021.3.9f1 - I assumed that was the correct version

Comment: Understood. I reverted your observation to the team. Hopefully, this will get addressed in an upcoming release.